# Getting IndentationError: expected an indented block in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# print the entire list of items
NBAfile = open ('NBA-Attendance-2015.txt', 'r')

for items in NBAlist: 

# Print out the team name, total attendance, average attendance, and capacity 
# with appropriate formatting 

print('The overall attendance at {0} was {1:,}, average attendance was {2:,} and the capacity was {3:.2f}%'.format(items[0], int(items[1]), int(items[2]), float(items[3])))

# Close the file 
NBAfile.close()
```

I tried the codes and got the error:

```
print('The overall attendance at {0} was {1:,}, average attendance was {2:,} and the capacity was {3:.2f}%'.format(items[0], int(items[1]), int(items[2]), float(items[3])))
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: can you show the whole code, this error means you have not aligned the code perfectly. make sure to use TAB not SPACE

Comment: Show your code properly formatted in the question.

Comment: The body of the `for` loop has to be indented.

Comment: It's really hard to type correct code to a terminal.  You should be using jupyter or a file editor.  But as @chepner points out, the body of a for loop needs to be indented.